# Science Fiction comic with detective

Tags: story-identification, comics

I read this comic book sometime last year on my kindle, and I am pretty sure it was a part of kindle comixology or something and since I have prime I got it for free.

It featured a detective as the main character who was solving a murder(?), and there was another character who was a rich woman and was the wife(?) of the dead man. The man character wore a helmet and I guess the story also featured some drug. The opening panel I think had the main character fighting some people.

I have added (?) to plot points I am not very sure of. The comic would be fairly recent and the whole comic gave the vibe of Cyberpunk 2077 or Blade Runner 2049.

The comic was definitely science fiction as the setting was futuristic and the now that I remember the above mentioned helmet was worn for some purpose , maybe to access memories or dreams something not 100% sure.

Comment: You call it a science fiction comic, but your description doesn't sound very science fictiony. Did it have a futuristic setting?

Comment: Can you come up with any more details? Other than the vibe you mention, this could be a [Dick Tracy comic](https://tribunecontentagency.com/premium-content/comics/dick-tracy/).

Comment: No certainly not a dick tracy comic, the artwork was much more modern

Comment: Sounds a little like Altered Carbon but I don't think they made that in to a comic.

Comment: @user14111, I would simply put the genre of the comic into scifi noir maybe

Comment: never mind i found it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Comic Book I was referring to was [Clear](https://www.amazon.in/Clear-comiXology-Originals-Scott-Snyder-ebook/dp/B09B1GM9XF)

I found it by digging into the very few comixology books I had and I found it clearly.

The plot synopsis -

> A sci-fi mystery thrill-ride into a strange dystopian future, where a neurological internet connection is transforming reality.

I was correct about few things but also wrong about some, there was no "drug" , it was a neurological internet connection.